# Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a sequence of dates/hours with this code, but I keep getting the error

> "Error in all_dates[cycle, 1] <- paste(c_dates[a], "-", c_hours[b],
>   "h") :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement
>   length"

The code used is this:

```
 years <- c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013) #1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)
    months <- c(6, 7, 8, 9)


for (i in years)
{

      upper.bound<- paste("01", months[1], i, sep="-")
      lower.bound <- paste("30", months[4], i, sep="-")

      c_dates <- seq(as.Date(upper.bound, "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date(lower.bound, "%d-%m-%Y"), "days")
      c_hours <- c(0, seq(0:22))

      len <- dim(as.matrix(c_dates))[1]*dim(as.matrix(c_hours))[1]

      all_dates <- data.frame()
      all_dates <- seq(0,0,length.out=len)

      dim(all_dates) <- c(dim(as.matrix(c_dates))[1]*dim(as.matrix(c_hours))[1], 1)

      cycle <- 1

      for(a in c_dates)
      {
        for(b in c_hours)
        {
          all_dates[cycle, 1] <- paste(c_dates[a], "-", c_hours[b], "h")
          cycle <- cycle + 1
        }
      }
}
```

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: What's `months`? And `i`. Your code fails on the first line.

Comment: Also, what is the value of `all_dates`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot a few lines of code. Everything relevant is there now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subset with an item of your vectors in your for loops.

Replace

```
   all_dates[cycle, 1] <- paste(c_dates[a], "-", c_hours[b], "h")
```

By

```
   all_dates[cycle, 1] <- paste(a, "-", b, "h")
```

Or change your loops to be:

```
for(a in 1:length(c_dates)){
for(b in 1:length(c_hours)){
```